# Bug in AWS Lambda policy editor?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have been getting a bug related to making a lambda policy. Here is the barebones one I am using for this example (note that the forum's formatting is crappy, I copy+pasted the exact code it gave me):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:CreateFunction",
                "lambda:DeleteFunction"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*:*:function:*"
        }
    ]

}
```

It tells me that I need to give it the function resource type, but this is literally the code the visual editor gives me.

To reproduce:

- Go to policy editor. For service, choose lambda.
- I gave it any two permissions for the function resource, but specifically create and delete.
- Under resources, for function, hit any.
- Go to the JSON editor. Copy the JSON. Delete it.
- Go back to the visual editor. Delete the lambda permission (by hitting "remove").
- Go back and paste the exact JSON you just copied. Now in the visual editor it will tell you that you haven't given it the resource type "function".

This has GOT TO BE a bug. I'm using the machine's own JSON.

Comment: not able to reproduce what you just entered. voting down to close the question.

Comment: Why would that be a 'vote to close', as opposed to 'okay so what's possibly the actual problem then'?

Comment: you never mentioned any problem and I fail to see one. Please do explain what is the problem.

Comment: If you think the policy editor is bugged then I would suggest reporting the problem to AWS and working around it by, perhaps using the awscli or an SDK to create your IAM policy.

Comment: _Where_ are you putting this policy? What do you mean by "visual editor"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, as your resource formatting is incorrect:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
      "Action": [
        "lambda:CreateFunction",
        "lambda:DeleteFunction"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```